# Are even numbers the sum of two odd sub-primes? / How to use computers to check?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science

Suppose
$$p_{a} + p_{b} = 2{p_{1}}^{m_{1}}{p_{2}}^{m_{2}}...{p_{n}}^{m_{n}} \qquad \text{where }p_{x} \in \mathbb{P} -\left\{2\right\} $$

Then

$$\frac{p_{a} + p_{b}}{{p_{1}}^{m_{1}}{p_{2}}^{m_{2}}...{p_{n}}^{m_{n}}} = 2$$

Not including $2$; all prime numbers are odd. Therefore $p_{x}=2q_{x}+1$ so

$$\frac{2q_{a}+1 + 2q_{b}+1}{{p_{1}}^{m_{1}}{p_{2}}^{m_{2}}\dots{p_{n}}^{m_{n}}} = 2 = \frac{2(q_{a} + q_{b}+1)}{{p_{1}}^{m_{1}}{p_{2}}^{m_{2}}\dots{p_{n}}^{m_{n}}}$$

Therefore

$$q_{a} + q_{b}+1= {p_{1}}^{m_{1}}{p_{2}}^{m_{2}}\dots{p_{n}}^{m_{n}}$$

Therefore $q_{a} + q_{b}$ must be even because ${p_{1}}^{m_{1}}{p_{2}}^{m_{2}}\dots{p_{n}}^{m_{n}} - 1$ must be even.

> For convenience we can call $q_{x}$ the sub-prime of the prime number $p_{x}$, where $q_{x} \in \mathbb{K}=\left\{1,2,3,5,6,8,9,11,14,15,18,20,21,23,26,29,...\right\}$ i.e $q_{x} = \frac{p_{x}-1}{2} : p_{x} \in \mathbb{P}-\left\{2\right\}$

$q_{a}$ and $q_{b}$ are either both odd or both even if the first supposition is true. Consequently it would follow that all even numbers are the sum of two sub-primes, but I ask,  are all even numbers the sum of two ${\bf odd}$ sub-primes, are there any counter examples? (And how could I check this myself, where can I learn or what software could I use?)

Comment: Are you forcing $p_a,p_b$ to fit your very first supposition? Or are you noting that for any $p_a,p_b$ the first supposition holds?

Comment: Just because all the sums of two odd primes are even doesn't mean that all even numbers can be written this way, but only some. Otherwise [Goldbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach's_conjecture) would not be still unproven after all this time.

Comment: I'm only forcing for thought, I realize its an unsolved conjecture.

Comment: The reason I asked about forcing the first supposition to hold is that if you take $p_a=3$ and $p_b=5$, then you get  $2^3$, which doesn't fit your first supposition. This also leads you to get $q_a=1$ and $q_b=2$ so that $q_a+q_b$ is odd.

Comment: @Josh Good point, thanks for pointing that out, I'm only supposing that even numbers which are not multiples of $2^n$ : $n>1$, are the sum of two primes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it would be helpful if you explicitly defined a subprime to be a positive integer $q$ such that $2q+1$ is prime.

The problem of writing a positive integer $N$ (even or not) as the sum of two subprimes is equivalent, as you noted, to the problem of whether $2N+2$ is the sum of two primes. As far as any ideas we have on how to approach such problems, the subprime version is just as hard as the original Goldbach version.

So in short, we don't know how to establish the conjecture that every integer $\ge2$ is the sum of two subprimes.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the note. The reason I ask is because I can only check a small amount of even numbers by hand, as I am not familiar with how to use computers to find counter examples for this problem; and I would like to test this for for more even numbers by computer, if no counter example is found.

Comment: It's a good exercise to program this check by hand, if you want to. But the original problem, and hence your reformulation, has been checked out past a billion billion already.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that it has been checked that even numbers are the sum of two odd sub-primes?

Comment: It has been checked that the first billion billion numbers, even and odd, are the sum of two subprimes. I don't know that anyone has checked that far restricting to odd subprimes.

Answer (score 1):

```
Monitor[
  Module[{p, t}, 
    Do[Catch[For[p = Prime[t = 2], p < n, p = Prime[++t], 
      If[Mod[p, 4] == 3 && PrimeQ[n - p], Throw[p]]]; 
    Print[n]], {n, 6, 1*^8, 4}]],
  Refresh[n, UpdateInterval -> .2, TrackedSymbols -> {}]]
```

In response to your question about how you could check this question numerically, here is Mathematica code that I used to verify your conjecture up to $N=10^8$. The actual version of your conjecture I used is:

> If $N\equiv2\pmod4$ and $N>2$, then $N$ is the sum of two primes $p,q\equiv3\pmod 4$.

It is not hard to see that this is equivalent to your formulation that every positive even number is the sum of two odd subprimes. Since the number theorists are still scratching their heads about Goldbach's conjecture, and your conjecture implies Goldbach's, this is probably the best you are going to get.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am struggling to see how they are equivalent because I don't really understand why you are using $3$ modulo $4$; the odd sub-primes are related to the prime numbers that are $3$ modulo $4$, but the odd sub-primes are not necessarily themselves $3$ modulo $4$, and obviously don't add up to the same even number that their prime counterparts do, plus they are not all prime.

Comment: Are you relying on some kind of morphism between those primes and sub-primes if so what kind of algebraic structure do they both have?

Comment: @BradGraham There is a one-to-one correspondence between odd subprimes and primes that are $3$ mod $4$ given by $p=2q+1$. Since this is an invertible linear map (from integers to odd numbers), you can easily convert these types of statements between subprimes and primes. I am not claiming that the odd subprimes are themselves $3$ mod $4$; they just have to be odd. But if $q_1,q_2$ are odd subprimes and $N'=q_1+q_2$, then using $p_1=2q_1+1,p_2=2q_2+1$ the sum of $p_1$ and $p_2$ is $N=2q_1+2q_2+2=2N'+2$. Since $N'$ was even, it follows that $N$ is $2$ mod $4$, and greater than $2$ since $N'>0$.

Comment: Thus assuming your statement, given any number $N\equiv 2$ mod $4$ and letting $N'=N/2-1$, $N'$ is positive even and hence $N'=q_1+q_2=\frac{p_1-1}2+\frac{p_2-1}2$ and $N=p_1+p_2$ (where $p_1,p_2\equiv3$ mod $4$ because $q_1,q_2$ are odd), proving my statement. And assuming my statement, given an even number $N'$ we know $2N'+2=p_1+p_2$ for primes $\equiv3$ mod $4$ (since $2N'+2$ is $2$ mod $4$), so $N'=\frac{p_1-1}2+\frac{p_2-1}2$ is a decomposition of $N'$ into odd subprimes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explains it!